# 7-Zip the files inside of folders

Tags: batch-file, command-line, compression, 7zip

I'd like to create a batch file to .7z the following below. So the batch.bat will be in the root folder where it will be executed and will zip the files inside folder1, folder2, folder3, etc., but the .7z won't create a folder. It just needs to zip the files in folders and create a separate .7z file with the title of that folder, but not create .7z with a folder.

```
root (batch.bat)
    folder1
        - file1.ext
    folder2
        - file1.ext
        - file2.ext
    folder3
        - file1.ext
        - file2.ext
        - file3.ext
```

This is the code I'm using to create a .7z of single files.

```
PATH %%PATH%%;"C:\Program Files\7-Zip";
FOR %%I IN (*.*) DO 7z.exe a -t7z -m0=LZMA2 -mx=5 -mmt=ON "%%~nI.7z" "%%I"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `for /D` loop that iterates through the directories in `\root`, which is wrapped around the `7z.exe` tool, like this:

```
for /D %%I in ("\root\*") do (
    pushd "%%~fI"
    "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -m0=LZMA2 -mx=5 -mmt=ON "%%~dpnxI.7z" ".\*"
    popd
)
```

Since `7z.exe` seems to store paths relative to the current working directory, I temporarily switch to every iterated one using `pushd` and `popd`.

I recommend to specify the `\root` path in an absolute manner (for example, `D:\Data`), so the batch program works from everywhere. However, if you do not want that, replace the `\root\*` part by `*`.

By the way, the `path` command is not needed when you specify the path directly when actually using `7z.exe`, like I did above (using the system variable `%ProgramFiles%` rather than a dedicated directory to which it points anyway).

However, your syntax is wrong anyway: you are actually setting the `PATH` variable to `%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\7-Zip";` literally, but I suppose you simply want to append `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip"` to it, for what you needed to write `PATH %PATH%;"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip"`.

Comment: Does the code mean this?

for each directory with all extensions store in I and do the following
Point to 7z.exe to add an archive, use .7z extension, compression method: LZMA2, compression level: Normal, enable multi-threading, create a file name based on the drive, path, file name. Not entirely sure what "%%~fI\*" does.

Also if I was to use the command you provided how would I change it for just individual file if the .bat file went in the folder? because if i run it, it also creates a 7z of the .bat

Comment: ...just fixed a minor issue (see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37311431/3)); I did not check your `7z.exe` command line options, I just copied them; beside that, you could understand my code like this: for every directory inside of `root`, create a `.7z` archive placed in `root` and named like the directory + `.7z`, containing all items from the directory; `%%~fI` points to the currently iterated directory by full path...

Comment: I fixed the stored paths in the `.7z` archives now (see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37311431/4)); in addition, I also described the `root` path...

Comment: Thank you! if I change the \root\* to * doesn't the * mean I can run it from any folder? because if I put the absolute path ("\C:\Users\NATLUF\Desktop\New folder\*") nothing happens.

Comment: So for each directory I change the absolute path `("C:\Users\NATLUF\Desktop\New folder\*")`? and if I just put the .bat file in the directory I should just change it to `("*")`, thanks

Comment: If you put `"C:\Users\NATLUF\Desktop\New folder\*"` as the `\root\*` part, you can run the batch script from anywhere and you will get the `.7z` archives as you want; if you just state `*`, the _current_ working directory is packed; if the batch file itself is also located in the current dir., it will be included in the archive as well...

Comment: Thanks for the help aschipfl! would you have any idea why the batch file doesn't copy the file name to the .7z file if it has a . in the name?

Comment: To keep the entire original name of the directory and append `.7z`, replace `"%%~dpnI.7z"` in the script by `"%%~dpnxI.7z"` -- I am going to update my answer accordingly...

Comment: thank you for you help! Do you think I should make another question regarding how to integrate another script inside the following one to change the file extension of all files inside of the directories to lowercase, some have numbers in the file name mixed with letters and some are just letters?

Comment: Of course you can post a new question about that issue. The only thing you should *not* do is to update this question with the new task, because this would change the scope and would therefore make all the current answers to appear incomplete or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
for /d %%I in ("*") do 7z.exe a -t7z -m0=LZMA2 -mx=5 -mmt=ON "%%I.7z" ".\%%I\*"
```

Comment: Thank you this also works! but just wondering if the batch file was placed in the folder3 directory to .7z the files individually my code above creates a .7z of the .bat file as well how to avoid this?

Comment: You said in the original post that the batch file is in the root. Why would it then be in Folder3? Anyway, you can exclude any file you want with the `-x!` option, for instance `-x!filename.bat`.  I'm curious why you accepted a different answer. I posted my answer first, it works, and it's less complicated.

Comment: I muddled up how I ask this second question what I meant was if the batch file is in root and the files are all in root as well not in directories how would I change the code to .7z them to individual .7z and still containing the same file name and excluding the batch file to be .7z, i figured it would be a different question and need to open up another question for it. Thanks for the reply on how to exclude the batch file.